# Scroll to the end of a page with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollto

Hello I am not a pro in Javascript.

But here is a question , I saw a website in which , the data keeps on loading as we scroll down .. ( eg : - facebook news feed )

Is there anything I can do to scroll to an end automatically ?

I searched a lot ad found out this

javascript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

will using this script in browser and hitting enter solve the problem ??

```
javascript:window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

I tried it but doesn't work. Can somebody help out

Thanks

NB: This is not my website , I want something to run in my browser which will scroll down the page.

Comment: that scrolls to bottom of the page. something else in your target site maybe preventing that.

Comment: I don't think you could put some code in browser and go straight to the end of any page that is feeded by scroll without coding the page itself, it will keep detecting as long as theres data to retrieve

Comment: Note that some browsers no longer support typing javascript into the URL bar; you may need to enter it into the console.

Comment: Facebook type loading is one piece at a time, somewhat ajax-ish - When you try to scroll to the bottom of the facebook page, it WILL, but then it will load more, because you've reached the bottom, then the bottom of the page will be lower again.